# Show that $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$ $f(x) = \text{exp}(-1/x^{2})$ if $x \neq 0$ is infinitely differentiable but not analytic at $x_{0} = 0$ `

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-functions

So taking the derivative of the latter half we get 
$$\left(\frac{2}{x^{3}}\right)e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2}}}$$ by chain rule. Im not sure how to find the derivative at x=0, and show that it equals 0 as it only produces more '1/0' expressions.
Additionally I assume to show it is not analytic at $x_0=0$, we use the taylor series for $e^{x}$ which is $$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
Where we substitute $\frac{-1}{x^{2}}$ for x to get 
$$e^{\frac{-1}{x^{2}}}=1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+\frac{1}{x^{4}2!}-\frac{1}{x^{6}3!}\cdots$$
So when we plug in x=0 this is invalid and thus is not analytic.

Is my latter attempt sufficient or do I need to add more? And how do I reach the conclusion that the function is differentiable at x=0.

Comment: "Im not sure how to find the derivative at x=0" By using the definition of derivative.

Comment: You have lost the minus sign in the exponent whilst taking the derivative, Dillain.

Comment: Oops yes I lost the minus sign. Also what do you mean by using definition? I don’t follow

Comment: @DillainSmith What is your definition of the derivative of a function?

Comment: @Travis so lim h->0 f(h)-f(0)/h-0 for exp(-1/x^2) but you cant even plug in 0 to the original function?

Comment: Your question title says $f(0) = 0$, no?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the function is infinitely differentiable you need some formula for the n-th derivative at points $x>0$. The fact that $f$ is not analytic is immediate from the fact that nonzero analytic functions cannot vanish on  a set with limit points.

Hints: prove by a simple induction argument that $f^{(n)} (x)=p_n(\frac 1 x) f(x)$ for some polynomial $p_n$.  Then change $x$ to $\frac 1 x$ and  use the fact that $\frac {e^{x}} {p(x)} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ for any polynomial $p$. [ This last fact follows by repeated application of L'Hopital's Rule].

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  You should be able to show the derivatives at $0$ are all $0$.  Thus the Taylor series at $0$ would be $0$.

Comment: Oh.  I didn't realize that.

Comment: But then the series converges to $0$, which is the value of the function at $0$. Do you mean that there is an $\epsilon$ with $f'(x)==0$ in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ so that the series converges to $0$ right of $x=0$?

Comment: Yes.  The function's power series is $0$, but the function is not zero.  So it can't be analytic.  Look up Taylor's theorem. It would be zero within the radius of convergence. @MSIS

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCuster: What if you restated to say it is only analytic in [a,b] or $[a -\epsilon,b]$?

Comment: @MSIS if it were analytic at $0$, it would be analytic in a nbhd of $0$.  But it can't be, because it isn't zero.

Answer (score 1):

I expect this is a duplicate of an existing question.

But if not, some hints are:

(1) Show by induction that, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ there is a rational function $r_n(x)$ such that
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = r_n(x)\exp(-1/x^q),\quad x \ne 0.
$$

(2) if $r(x)$ is a ratonal function, then
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} r(x)\exp(-1/x^2) = 0.
$$

Comment: So the contradiction is that $e^{-1/x^2}$ is zero in a neighborhood $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ of 0, which is not the case (specifically in (0, \epsilon))?

Answer (score 0):

Every Real -analytic function $f(x)$ is the Real part of a complex function $F(z)=U+iV$. Since f is compact and continuous, it is bounded. Since $f$ , the Real part ,is bounded, so is $F(z)$ , its Complex extension. Then $F(z)$ is an entire, bounded function, and so must be constant, which it is not -- a contradiction.